# Is there a way to bind react-apollo to a single component instead of wrapping entire app?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-apollo, apollo-client

I'm looking for the way to bind apollo to single components instead of wrapping the entire app, since we don't want to bind all our architecture to a service, now that we would use apollo only to retrieve data for a single component, and the way we retrieve that data could even change over time and maybe not use graphql anymore, or want to bind different graphql services to different components, so wrapping the entire app into an apollo provider is not our best choice.

Is there some way to avoid it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping entire app is needed to:

- use shared, common cache as a single source of truth;
- access from different places/app components.

**You can wrap only one component if you wish.**

### You don't have to wrap any components to use graphql.

You can use "normal" `fetch`/`axios` requests to retrieve required data.

Comment: Thank  you very much, I'm newbie with React and Apollo and every tutorial I've found wraps the entire app, I don't know how would that approach work. Do you know where can I find an example?

Comment: I noticed you said "to use GRAPHQL", You mean avoid using Apollo?

Comment: If caching client with normalization (apollo) is not required ... you can simply fetch json data from graphql endpoint like https://stackoverflow.com/q/52904569/6124657